# Chrome extension crashes when trying to access from two different windows?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I open a chrome extension, then open a new window (incognito for example) and try to open the extension again, it crashes. I then need to reload the app through the chrome extensions page. There are no errors in this.

The question is how can I work with the extension from different windows at the same time

```json
{
    "manifest_version": 2,

    "name": "Such Activity",
    "description": "Wow",
    "version": "1.0",
    "permissions": ["tabs","webRequest", "webRequestBlocking", "storage", "http://*/","https://*/"],

    "browser_action": {
        "default_title": "Click Me",
        "default_popup": "popup.html",
        "default_icon": "start.png" 
    }
}
```

and my popup.js

```js
function injectTheScript() {
    console.log("start script")
    if (nfts.length <= 0) {
        console.log("successfull")
        return;
    }
    id = nfts.pop()
    var newURL = "url"+id;
    chrome.tabs.update({url: newURL}, myTab => {
        function listener(tabId, changeInfo, tab) {
            if (tabId === myTab.id && changeInfo.status == 'complete') {
                chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, tabs => {
                    chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, {file: "content_script.js"});
                })
                counter++;
                document.getElementById('count').textContent = counter
                console.log("hoba"+counter)
                setTimeout(injectTheScript, 7000);
            }
        };
        if (!isInjected) {
            chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(listener);
            isInjected = true;
        }
    });
}
document.getElementById('clickactivity').addEventListener('click', injectTheScript)

chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(
  function(details) { 
    return { cancel: true }; 
  },
  {urls: ["*://*/*checkUser"]},
  ["blocking"]
);
```

the extension crashes before I interact with it. it crashes when i click on its icon in chrome

Comment: Sounds like a bug in Chrome. See if it's fixed in Chrome Canary.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bug in stable version Chrome, it's fixed in Chrome Canary

thx [wOxxOm](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3959875/woxxom) for

Comment: This should be comment not as answer.